# Varias dudas creando un syntax theme en Atom

Tags: atom-editor, theme

#### Hola, estoy intentando crear un syntax theme como el ya existente *Classic Plus* de Dev-C++.

**Mis preguntas son:**

**1**: ¿Cómo puedo poner `#include <>` con `color: @green;` y `font-weight: normal;` pero manteniendo esto?:

`&.syntax--control {
    color: @syntax-text-color;
    font-weight: bold;
  }`

**2**: ¿Cómo puedo poner `()`,`{}`,`,`,`.`,`;`...  con `color: @red;` y `font-weight: bold;`?

Os dejo una imagen de cómo se ve esto en Dev-C++:

[image: captura devcpp]

Y ahora, cómo se ve esto si lo pongo en *Atom*:

[image: captura atom]

Si necesitáis ver mi `base.less`, decídmelo y la añado.

Muchísimas gracias. :-)

Alberto.

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate the question.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.SO], te sugiero traducir la pregunta ya que el idioma oficial es el Español, también pásate por el [tour] y también lee [ask].